# Date_format() works for me but it doesn't for co-owner of the website

Tags: php, date, format

I have a very specific problem. I use this code:

`<?php      $ScheduleDate = date_create($LeagueGeneralMenu['DatabaseCreationDate']); echo date_Format($ScheduleDate,"M j"); ?>`

When I upload the database, everything is alright. However, when co-owner of website uploads a database, we get this message:
**WARNING: DATE_FORMAT() EXPECTS PARAMETER 1 TO BE DATETIMEINTERFACE, BOOLEAN GIVEN IN ...**

It's kind of headscratcher for me since this code works for me but not for the co-owner. Do you have a clue where could be a problem?

Thanks!

Comment: We need more data, especially the part that defines `$LeagueGeneralMenu` values.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To help people find your question please remember to add the appropriate tag for your programming language. In this case I added the php tag, please correct if not appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is data related issue in you LeagueGeneralMenu['DatabaseCreationDate'] property.
Could you try handling the exception by checking if LeagueGeneralMenu['DatabaseCreationDate'] has a valid DateTime value and then only format!

You can show as it is if not a valid DateTime so that you will know what kind of data is being fetched!